# Service in OSGi not getting register

Tags: osgi, aem

I am trying to register a simple service in OSGi but, its not visible in the felix console once i write @Reference . Below is my service.

```
@Component(metatype = true , immediate = true)
@Service(value = LoginAccessService.class)
@Properties({
        @Property(name = "service.vendor", value = "AEM.Training"),
        @Property(name = "service.description", value = "Login Access Testing")
})
public class LoginAccessImpl implements LoginAccessService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginAccessImpl.class);
    @Reference
    protected AbstractSlingRepository2 repository;

    @Override
    public Node createNode(String path) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

In Case if I write

```
    @Reference
    protected SlingRepository repository;
```

Its reflect in felix. Any Idea how this happens.

Comment: Is your project bundle in active state when you build the code with AbstractSlingRepository2 ?

Comment: Probably there is no OSGi service available in the OSGi container that is registered with the AbstractSlingRepository2 type.

Comment: My Bundle is active & dependencies are resolved. org.apache.sling.jcr.base.AbstractSlingRepository2

Comment: Check the OSGi console. First if the bundle is active, then if your component is active. If not, check the details. In the bundle you would see unresolvable dependencies and in the component unsatisfied references.

Comment: Yes component is in unsatisfied state ["Unsatisfied","Service Name: org.apache.sling.jcr.base.AbstractSlingRepository2","Multiple: single","Optional: mandatory","Policy: static","No Services bound"] . But why so

Comment: This means, that there is no Service registered implementing this AbstractSlingRepository2. I honestly never heard of it before. Why do you need this? And as it seems to be abstract there is probably no instance available (you can't instanciate abstract classes). So you need to find an interface/class that extends this abstract class and is available in OSGi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Only the interface can be referenced since the `@Service` can be [registered only by its interface(s)](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html#service). And the AbstractSlingRepository2 is an abstract class, not interface.
2. The [AbstractSlingRepository2](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/jcr/base/AbstractSlingRepository2.html) is available only in Sling v7 which is used in AEM (CQ) since **v6.0**

So using

```
@Reference
protected SlingRepository repository;
```

is a proper way to get the repository.